# Trigger email send when a rails model boolean field is set to true instead of false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, triggers, mailer

I have two models in my application. Families has_many Individuals's. individuals's belongs_to Families.

I'm trying to make it so that when a boolean field in the Families model is set to "true" an email is sent to all of the email addresses stored against Individuals when the family is "updated".

Can anyone help with this? I've been able to get ActiveMailer sending an email when an Individual is created easily enough, but cannot find a way to trigger on the update of a specific field?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an extension of this question, is there any way to make it so that instead of relying on `"boolean_field_changed?"`, I can trigger the email when the value is `true` as opposed to `false`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use an after filter?

on the Family model

```
after_update :email_individuals


private
def email_individuals
  if boolean_field_changed?
    individuals.each do |i|
      // send out emails here
    end
  end
end
```

The next step would be to move this out of the request cycle and into a queue.

Hope I grokked your question properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm getting closer all the time.

I get an error now about an `undefined method 'message_id' for #,Individual:......);

Not quite sure how to resolve it.

Comment: I take that back. I just received about 20 emails! Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to hit me up on twitter @mattallen if you need me.

Answer (score 3):

Toby has the right idea but I disagree that this should be implemented in the controller... this is much better suited to a model after_update callback. something like this:

```
def update_fired
  if yourfield_changed?
     #send mail here
  end
end
```

Then just make sure in your model you set the method to be the after_update callback

Comment: I like to add the conditional earlier: `after_update :update_fired, :if => "yourfield_changed?"`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to add something to the update action of your controller

```
if individual.boolean_field_changed? and individual.boolean_field
  individuals.each do |ind|
    Mailer.deliver_mail(ind)
  end
end
```

Rails has an API for detecting changes in model fields (in the above case you add _changed? to the field name and it will tell you if the field has been changed.

Comment: OK. Thanks for this. But would this be in the Families controller, or the individuals controller? Also the field that is changing is stored against the family, not the individual.

Would this work? 

    `if family.boolean_field_changed? and family.boolean_field
      individuals.each do |ind|
        Mailer.deliver_mail(ind)
      end
    end`

Comment: Think the others are right, add it to the model, not the controller.

Comment: And yeah, put it in whatever object has the values. Either one works the same.